# Display Partial view in same View mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

In my application, I have loaded the partial view in my common View using div.load() jquery.
I am trying to update the values in my partial view and display the partial view in the same view using jquery. Is there any other methods or samples to implement it.

**Common View**

```
 <body>
    <div class="block-content" style="width: 200px;">
     <ul>
      <li><a id="MyAccount" class="common"><strong>Account Dashboard</strong></a></li>
      <li><a id="AccountDetails" class="common">Account Information</a></li>
      <li><a id="AddressBook" class="common">Address Book</a></li>
      <li><a id="MyOrders" class="common">My Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="divDynamic" class="order">
    </div>
    </body>
```

**jQuery to diaplay the partial view on click of the link**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.common').click(function () {
                var pageid = this.id;
                LoadPartialView(pageid);
            });
        });

        function LoadPartialView(pageid) {
            $("#divDynamic").empty();
            $("#divDynamic").load("/WPindex/" + pageid,
            function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                alert("An error occurred while loading the results.");
                }
            });

        }
 </script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AccountDetails()
{
  return PartialView(); 
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AccountDetails(string FirstName, string LastName,
string Email, string DOB,string PhoneNo, string Gender)
{
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

**jQuery to Update the partial view values and load the partial view in same view**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.button').click(function () {
   LoadPartialView();
 });
 });
 function LoadPartialView() {  
var FirstName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
var LastName = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
var DOB = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
var PhoneNo = document.getElementById("PhoneNo").value;
var Gender = $('#Gender optionelected').attr('value'); 

 $("#divDynamic").load("/ControllerName/AccountDetails?", { 
 'FirstName': FirstName,'LastName': LastName, 'Email': Email,
 'DOB': DOB, 'PhoneNo': PhoneNo,'Gender':Gender
  },
  function (response, status, xhr) {
   if (status == "error") {
  alert("An error occurred while loading the results.");
   }                     
  });  
  }
```

I tried to update the partial view values and to display the partial view in same View.
I face a strong performance issue while using partial view. Any mistake in my code. ?
Is my approach is wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

Put breakpoint in both of the `AccountDetails` action methods.
I think that the load method use get method in the request and your second action method is decorated with `HttpPost` attribute.
Try use the `ajax` method of the jQuery: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var myUrl = "/ControllerName/AccountDetails?FirstName=" + FirstName +
    "&LastName=" + LastName + 
    // ... other query strings ...        

$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,        
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        $("#divDynamic").html(jqXHR.reponseText); 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert(jqXHR.responesText); 
    }
    // ... any other ajax options ...
});
```

Comment: Is there any other method than jquery to update/post in partial view to display in same view as it gives performance issues.

Comment: @kk1076 - Yeah you can use `@Ajax.BeginForm()` in your partial view.